# Метод wall.get (VK API) — Как вывести записи на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api

Есть код, который выводит текст записей. А как выводить картинки записей так, чтобы работало? А то я пробовал — у меня не работало!

```js
var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=1&count=20&filter=all&v=5.45';
var answer;
$(document).ready(function()
{      
  $.ajax
  ({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response)
        {
         answer = response;
         answer.response.items.forEach(function(item)
      {
        if((item.text != 'undefined') && (item.text != ''))
        {
          console.log(item.text);
        }
      });
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
         console.log('Ошибка');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Как конкретно пытались вывести картинки и что именно не работало?

Comment: у вас ошибка в урле, и нет там никаких картинок http://jsbin.com/yopajupaje/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @Jean-Claude  есть там картинки, только они не в поле `text` ...и нормальный у автора УРЛ. не сбивайте с толку

Answer (score 2):

Вы хоть в json заглядывали, там ниже text есть картинки в любом размере `JSON.response.items[1].attachments[0].photo.photo_604`:
Поставьте для фокса плагин JSON-handle - он позволяет бродить по json.

Итого: в `JSON.response.items[1].attachments` хранятся прикрепленные файлы, массив. Далее `JSON.response.items[1].attachments[0].photo` - тут объект с свйоствами фото, его разные размеры, высота и ширина `JSON.response.items[1].attachments[0].photo.photo_604` или c шириной 130 `JSON.response.items[1].attachments[0].photo.photo_130`. Если фото несколько, выводите их циклом.

```css
#testvk {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=gamer_by_life&count=5&filter=all&v=5.45&callback=?';
  var answer, output ='';
  $(document).ready(function()
  {   
   $.ajax
   ({
    url: url,                
    type: 'get',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
     answer = response;
     answer.response.items.forEach(function(item)
     {
      if((item.text != 'undefined') && (item.text !== ''))
      {
       output += '<div id="testvk"><p id="textvk">' + item.text + '</p>';
       if (item.attachments !== undefined) {
        for(var i = 0, length1 = item.attachments.length; i < length1; i++){
         if (item.attachments[i].type == 'photo') {
         //console.log(item.attachments[i]);
         output += '<img src="' + item.attachments[i].photo.photo_130 + '">';
        }
       }
      }
      output += '</div>';
     }
    });    
     document.body.innerHTML = output;
    },
    error: function(error)
    {
     console.log(error);
    }
   }); 
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что аттачмент[0]? Их может быть несколько. с чего вы взяли что `photo`? там может быть и в видео и в стикерах и в линках и в репостах.... с чего вы взяли что `photo_604` ? в зависимости от аттачмента может быть разные виды фото, а может и не быть

Comment: с того, что он видимо вообще не может углубиться.

Comment: Именно поэтому я написал, чтоб ТС уточнил....Может он другое имел в виду) ........ кстати аттачмента тоже может вообще не быть

Comment: обновил примерчик.

Comment: Как вывести это в див в таком формате? <div id="testvk"><p id="textvk"></p><img src="imagevk"></div>

Comment: @arthru внутри цикла `for()` можете прописать вывод во что угодно.

Comment: Да но как того поместить все и текст и картнки в один див?

Comment: @arthru ничему так не научишься если за тебя все будут делать, сделал http://jsbin.com/tafeboseri/edit?html,css,output

Comment: меняю домен группы и че то не работает

Comment: значит плохо меняешь

Comment: вот ставлю так owner_id=-78812318

Comment: и перестает работать

Comment: даже в таком формате не работает domain=gamer_by_life

Comment: дополнил код в ответе, у вас не в каждом посте есть фото, потому и не работало, так правильно `domain=gamer_by_life`. Из темы удаляюсь. Более не отвечаю.